# ORACLE SQL IN Clause (SQL Query)

Tags: sql, oracle, replace

I'm having `:` delimited column like `1:2:3:`. I want to get this into `1,2,3`. My query looks like,

```
select name 
from status where id IN (SELECT REPLACE(NEXT_LIST,':',',')
                         FROM status);
```

but I got an error

> ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: which column exactly? could you show some sample data?

Comment: Replace function is used to update the content of a string, I think id column is Numeric field that's the reason its giving error.

Comment: column next_list having data like this '2:3:4' and id column having 1,2,3,4 and name column having like this thamarai, dmitry,raffaello

Comment: In the ID column, each row contains one number, right? In this case your query is not possible because you check if e.g. _"1"_ is in _"1,2,3"_. you could `to_char` the ID ind compare it to the statement with `LIKE`

Comment: BTW: Your query is also incorrect concerning the tables. You certainly don't query the table status to get IDs in order to query it again to get names. So this is a strange example. Is the column NEXT_LIST in a table with one row only? Please show a proper query.

Answer (score 2):

`(1, 2, 3, 4)` is different from `('1, 2, 3, 4')`. `IN` requires the former, a list of values; you give it the latter, a string.

You have two options mainly:

1. Build the query dynamically, i.e. get the list first, then use this to build a query string.
2. Tokenize the string. This can be done with a custom pipelined function or a recursive query, maybe also via some XML functions. Google "Oracle tokenize string" to find a method that suits you.

**UPDATE** Option #3: Use LIKE as in `':1:2:3:4:' like '%:3:%'`
(This requires your next_list to contain only simple numbers separated with colons. No leading zeros, no blanks, no other characters.)

```
select name 
from status 
where (select ':' || next_list || ':' from status) like '%:' || id || ':%'
```

Comment: This depends on what language your app is written in. Pseudo code: `list := sqlExecute("SELECT REPLACE(NEXT_LIST,':',',') FROM status"); names := sqlExecute("SELECT name FROM status WHERE id IN (" + list + ")");`

Answer (score 1):

i agreed with Thorsten but i wonder if we just replace one more time would it works? i mean like this:

```
 select name 
 from status where id IN (SELECT replace(REPLACE(NEXT_LIST,':',','),'''','')
                            FROM status);
```

Comment: No this cannot work. No matter how many string operations you apply, this remains a string. And the string itself doesn't contain a quote. The quote is only the delimiter we use when we need a string *literal*.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner got it and thanks for the explain, saw your answer above Nice

Answer (score 0):

The `REPLACE` function returns a string, so the nested query returns a list of string values (where colons replaced with commas), but not a list of number values. When Oracle engine interprets `id IN (str_value)` it tries to cast the `str_value` to number and raises exception `ORA-01722: invalid number` because there are cases like '1:2:3' which are definetely unparseable.

The "pure sql" approach leads us to using custom function detecting if a number is in a colon-separated list:

```
-- you need Oracle 12c to use function in the WITH clause
-- on earlier versions just unwrap CASE statement and put it into query
WITH
  FUNCTION in_list(p_id NUMBER, p_list VARCHAR2) RETURN NUMBER DETERMINISTIC IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN CASE WHEN
           instr(':' || p_list || ':', ':' || p_id || ':') > 0        
      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
  END;
SELECT *
FROM status 
WHERE in_list(id, next_list) = 1;
```

Here I assume that values in the `next_list` column are strings containing numbers separated with colon without spaces. In common case you shall modify the function to match specific list formats.